# How to pass arguments from Flutter to Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

i've got started studying Flutter. I'm trying to using MethodChannel and MethodCall to communicate with Android platform. I don't know how to pass arguments to the Android code.

Below is my code.

```
// dart
void _onClick() async {
    var parameters = {'image':'starry night'};
    await platform.invokeMethod('showToast', new Map.from(parameters));
}


// kotlin
MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
    Log.d("MainActivity", ">> ${call.method}, ${call.arguments}")
    when (call.method) {
        "showToast" -> {
        showToast("toast")
    }
    else -> {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "fail");
    }
}
```

I can check an arguement value what I passed by log message what I printed.
`{image=starry night}`
But I don't know how to parse to a map object.

Comment: have you tried casting `call.arguments` to `Map`? I'm not sure what's your question...

Comment: @StefanGolubović Thanks
`val arguments = call.arguments as java.util.HashMap<String, String>` works fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Flutter

On the Flutter side, you can pass arguments by including them as a map in the `invokeMethod` call.

```
_channel.invokeMethod('showToast', {'text': 'hello world'});
```

#### Kotlin

On the Kotlin side you can get the parameters by casting `call.arguments` as a Map or getting a particular argument from `call.argument()`.

```
override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
  when (call.method) {
    "showToast" -> {
      val text = call.argument<String>("text") // hello world
      showToast(text)
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the Java Code as well? Any example?

Comment: I don't have the Java code but if anyone else does feel free to edit this answer or add another answer with it.

Answer (score 6):

**Dart side (sending data)**

```dart
var channel = MethodChannel('foo_channel');
var dataToPass = <String, dynamic>{
  'os': 'Android',
};
await channel.invokeListMethod<String>('methodInJava', dataToPass);
```

**Java side (receiving data):**

```java
if (methodCall.method.equals("methodInJava")) {
    // Get the entire Map.
    HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) methodCall.arguments;
    Log.i("MyTag", "map = " + map); // {os=Android}

    // Or get a specific value.
    String value = methodCall.argument("os");
    Log.i("MyTag", value); // Android
}
```